# Grails 2.4.3 & MySQL & grails.project.fork = false

Tags: mysql, grails, intellij-idea, fork, mode

I have switched from Grails 2.2.4 to Grails 2.4.3 and experienced bad problems with my IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 IDE.

After creating a clean Grails 2.4.3 project and adding a clean controller class I start the project via "run-app" in IntelliJ IDEA. Afterwards I change something in the controller and I get the following exceptions:

```
2014-09-29 18:45:41,801 [Thread-11] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin 
[controllers:2.4.3] could not reload changes to file [D:\VS\Eclipse Workspace\xx\grails-app\controllers\com\xx\backoffice\MaintenanceController.groovy]: Cannot get property 'cacheOperationSource' on null object
Message: Cannot get property 'cacheOperationSource' on null object
   Line | Method
->> 184 | doCall in CacheGrailsPlugin$_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

.....................Error 
|
2014-09-29 18:45:43,276 [FileSystemWatcher: files=#175 cl=groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader@177f04d9] ERROR agent.Watcher  - FileWatcher caught serious error, see cause
Message: loader (instance of  org/springsource/loaded/ChildClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/xx/MaintenanceController$$DOrGoSVQ"
   Line | Method
->> 791 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   634 | defineClass in     ''
^   722 | run . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

My BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.reload.enabled = true

forkConfig = [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false]
grails.project.fork = [
// configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked     compilation is required
//  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

// configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
test: forkConfig,
// configure settings for the run-app JVM
run: forkConfig,
// configure settings for the run-war JVM
war: forkConfig,
// configure settings for the Console UI JVM
console: forkConfig
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.dependency.cache.dir = "${userHome}/.m2/repository"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "info" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}

dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'


}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"


    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.6"
    compile ":shiro:1.2.1"
    compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5" // or
    //runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
}
```

I did some research and found out that I have to disable the forked mode as IDEA has problems with that. Therefor I disabled this feature in the BuildConfig.groovy with the **grails.project.fork = false** option.

Now I can't start the app via "run-app" because of the following exceptions:

```
2014-09-29 18:48:56,144 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
    Line | Method
->> 1094 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    997 | createSQLException in     ''
|    983 | createSQLException in     ''
|    928 | createSQLException in     ''
|    959 | createSQLException in     ''
|    949 | createSQLException in     ''
|    432 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->> 7467 | realClose          in com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    923 | close              in     ''
|    801 | convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4445 | scanForAndThrowDataTruncation in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2923 | sqlQueryDirect . . in     ''
|   2820 | execSQL            in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2769 | execSQL . . . . .  in     ''
|   1569 | executeQuery       in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|   4210 | loadServerVariables in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   3604 | initializePropsFromServer in     ''
|   2542 | connectOneTryOnly  in     ''
|   2309 | createNewIO        in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . in     ''
|     46 | <init>             in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    408 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Error |
2014-09-29 18:48:56,203 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
    Line | Method
->> 1094 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    997 | createSQLException in     ''
|    983 | createSQLException in     ''
|    928 | createSQLException in     ''
|    959 | createSQLException in     ''
|    949 | createSQLException in     ''
|    432 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->> 7467 | realClose          in com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    923 | close              in     ''
|    801 | convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4445 | scanForAndThrowDataTruncation in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2923 | sqlQueryDirect . . in     ''
|   2820 | execSQL            in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2769 | execSQL . . . . .  in     ''
|   1569 | executeQuery       in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|   4210 | loadServerVariables in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   3604 | initializePropsFromServer in     ''
|   2542 | connectOneTryOnly  in     ''
|   2309 | createNewIO        in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . in     ''
|     46 | <init>             in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    408 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Error |
2014-09-29 18:48:56,251 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
    Line | Method
->> 1094 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    997 | createSQLException in     ''
|    983 | createSQLException in     ''
|    928 | createSQLException in     ''
|    959 | createSQLException in     ''
|    949 | createSQLException in     ''
|    432 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->> 7467 | realClose          in com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    923 | close              in     ''
|    801 | convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4445 | scanForAndThrowDataTruncation in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2923 | sqlQueryDirect . . in     ''
|   2820 | execSQL            in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2769 | execSQL . . . . .  in     ''
|   1569 | executeQuery       in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|   4210 | loadServerVariables in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   3604 | initializePropsFromServer in     ''
|   2542 | connectOneTryOnly  in     ''
|   2309 | createNewIO        in     ''
|    834 | <init> . . . . . . in     ''
|     46 | <init>             in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    408 | handleNewInstance  in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance        in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun           in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                in java.lang.Thread

Error |
2014-09-29 18:48:56,269 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->> 1094 | createSQLException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    997 | createSQLException in     ''
|    983 | createSQLException in     ''
|    928 | createSQLException in     ''
|    959 | createSQLException in     ''
|    949 | createSQLException in     ''
|    432 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoSuchMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.removeOpenResultSet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;)V
->> 7467 | realClose in com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    923 | close     in     ''
|    801 | convertShowWarningsToSQLWarnings in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4445 | scanForAndThrowDataTruncation in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2923 | sqlQueryDirect in     ''
|   2820 | execSQL   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2769 | execSQL . in     ''
|   1569 | executeQuery in com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl
|   4210 | loadServerVariables in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   3604 | initializePropsFromServer in     ''
|   2542 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2309 | createNewIO in     ''
|    834 | <init> .  in     ''
|     46 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    408 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    419 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    344 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

My DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
    reload = false

}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoreconnect=true"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
            username = ""
            password = ""
        }
    }
    test {
        pooled = true
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoreconnect=true"
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        properties {
            // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
            jmxEnabled = true
            initialSize = 5
            maxActive = 50
            minIdle = 5
            maxIdle = 25
            maxWait = 10000
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            validationInterval = 15000
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = false
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
            defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        }
        username = ""
        password = ""
    }

    production {

        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?autoreconnect=true"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
            username = ""
            password = ""
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea how I could solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this post: [Grails 2.4.3 fails to reload controller or service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045344/grails-2-4-3-fails-to-reload-controller-or-service)

If it doesn´t help please provide your BuildConfig.groovy