# Grails upgrading 1.3.7 to 2.4.4 - recompiling entire project after doing a minute change in part of code

Tags: grails

We have upgraded our project from grails 1.3.7 to 2.4.4 version. In this we are facing some issues. Each and every time when we do some changes in controllers or services, we have to recompile the entire project once again. So that our development time gets affected. Currently using grails 2.4.4 version and STS 3.6.4 as IDE. Using older grails versions 1.3.7 and 2.2.4, this problem does not arise.

What's the solution to overcome this recompiling problem? How to make the changes to be affected without recompiling each and every time.

Is there any alternative IDE to work with grails 2.4.4 to overcome this recompiling issue, if this issue persists in STS 3.6.4 IDE.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: is project build automatically ticked ?

Comment: yes, project build automatically is checked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045344/grails-2-4-3-fails-to-reload-controller-or-service try disabling the forking setting it to be =[] nothing in brackets or entire block and try to see if it goes away

Comment: @vahid ---> disabling the forking setting it to be =[] nothing in brackets. i get another exception like,                                                                                                              "  |Loading Grails 2.4.4
Error |
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: argument type mismatch"

Answer (score 0):

What error are you seeing, when you say "we have to recompile the entire project once again"?

I have a Grails 2.4.4 project where there is a (temporary) conflict between the maven repository and the local 'lib' folder, and this causes a 'ClassNotFoundException' error unless you do 'grails clean refresh-dependencies'.

A workaround that I discovered for that is to save a meaningless change to BuildConfig.groovy, like adding text to a comment line in BuildConfig each time before doing 'run-app' or 'test-app'. Then that 'ClassNotFoundException' goes away.